# subtracting integer from string textview

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to replace a textview that has the contents "330" after either some addition or subtraction has occurred with fixed numbers.

for example

```
int points = 75
totalPoints = totalPoints - points
```

I think I have managed to get the data from the string and convert it into an integer but i am having trouble putting the result back into the textview

this is what i have tried so far but get a result of 2131230752

```
TextView tmpTxtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.premPoints);
int adjustPoints = Integer.valueOf(R.id.premPoints);

switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.premTeam1:
points = 75;
adjustPoints = adjustPoints - points;
tmpTxtview.setText(String.valueOf(adjustPoints));
break;

case R.id.premTeam2:
points = 74;
adjustPoints = adjustPoints - points;
tmpTxtview.setText(String.valueOf(adjustPoints));
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
int adjustPoints = Integer.valueOf(R.id.premPoints);
```

into this:

```
int adjustPoints = Integer.valueOf(tmpTextview.getText());
```

(if it doesn't work, use `tmpTextview.getText().toString()` instead).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `Integer.parseInt()` instead of `Integer.valueOf()`.

Comment: just tested this and i get an error under valueOf asking to cast arg1 to string so changed to `int adjustPoints = Integer.valueOf((String) tmpTxtview.getText());` and it works, thanks

Comment: added the `.toString();` instead of casting and that worked as well